# Printing the unhidden columns in extjs 3.3.1 columnmodel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Is there anyway to print the only the unhidden columns in Ext Js 3.3.1 . I'm using a columnmodel to implement the grid design.

What I'm trying to do is export only the unhidden columns. The logic for export is fine now what I need help is in storing the unhidden columns and pass them. I'm sharing a piece of code but I don't code will be of a big use.

Suppose I have table having columns

#### Name Place Animal Thing

Now I unhide the  Animal column.

#### Name Place Thing

my code is as below

```
var columnmodel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns:[
        {header: "Name", id: "id", , sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Name'},
        {header: "Place", id: "entityType", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Place'},
        {header: "Animal", id: "title", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'title'},
        {header: "Thing", id: "title", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'title'},
    ],
    listeners: {
        {@link #hiddenchange}: function(cm, colIndex, hidden)   {
            saveConfig(colIndex, hidden);
        }
    }
});
```

Here I to see which columns are hidden and which are not i.e. My console should say

Unhidden Columns are :- Name Place Thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.
Give this a try:

```
listeners: {
    hiddenchange: function (cm) {
        var visibileCols = [];
        Ext.each(cm.columns, function(col){
            if(!col.hidden){
                visibileCols.push(col.header);
            }
        });
        console.log(visibileCols);
        // you should use: return visibileCols 
        // or store them in a grid property...
   }
}
```

Comment: No Alex the changes are not working, but yes you understood the problem correctly.

Comment: In what way are they not working? I've tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7F6nS/18/

Comment: Also check this: http://jsfiddle.net/7F6nS/19/ (it also has an alert which displays all visible columns)